# Test is not abstract and does not override abstract method getServletConfig() in javax.servlet.Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

**The code:**

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test implements Servlet {
  public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    System.out.println("i am init().........");
  }

  public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("i am service().........");
  }

  public void destroy() {
    System.out.println("i am destory().........");
  }

  public String getServletInfo() {
    return "servlet version ";
  }
}
```

**The ERROR:**

```
Test.java:4: Test is not abstract and does not override abstract method getServletConfig() in javax.servlet.Servlet

public class Test implements Servlet
       ^
```

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 2):

Usually you should extend the abstract servlet where it has default implementation of some methods.

Don't implement `Servlet` from scratch.

Because when you put `implements` clause on the class you have to write code for all abstract methods of that abstract class or interface where all methods are abstract, i.e. pure virtual. The exception can be mentioned in Java 8 interfaces can have default implementations for some methods.

## the example of servlet:

```
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
      ...
   }
   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
      doGet(request, response);
   }
   ...
}
```

To learn more how to create servlet see a technology lesson:

## **[Writing Servlets](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/servlet-142430.html)**

> All servlet classes extend the `HttpServlet` abstract class. `HttpServlet`
>   simplifies writing HTTP servlets by providing a framework for handling
>   the HTTP protocol. Because `HttpServlet` is abstract, your servlet class
>   must extend it and override at least one of its methods. An abstract
>   class is a class that contains unimplemented methods and cannot be
>   instantiated itself.
>
> ```java
> public class ExampServlet extends HttpServlet {
>   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
>          HttpServletResponse response)
>          throws ServletException, IOException {
>     ...
>   }
> }
> ```